# Build Angular Translate with Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, angular-translate

I'm using Yeoman to build an Angular app, with Grunt.

I'm using [Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate), and got a problem when I build the app with Grunt with the module [Grunt Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/grunt-angular-translate).

I have 2 languages, french and english (`fr.json` & `en.json`), in a `app/translations` folder.

I have this config in my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
i18nextract: {
  default_options: {
    src: ['app/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.json'],
    suffix: '.json',
    lang: ['fr', 'en'],
    dest: 'dist/translations',
    jsonSrc: ['app/translations/*.json']
  }
}
```

This create 2 files, `fr.json` & `en.json` in `dist/translations`, each contains all translations key, but not the corresponding values:

For example:

```
"email-in": "",
"email-out": "",
"call-in": "",
"call-out": "",
```

I tried many configurations but couldn't find the right one to solve this.

Thanks for your help.